# how can set a auto decrement id of table in sqlite when delete a row?

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite

i have a table with delete func,i want when deleted a row,IDs other rows at next rows,decrement atuomaticly.or in other word move up(re-insert) rows.

```
create table %s"+"(%s int primary key, %s String, %s String, %s String)",
                            TABLE_VIEW, COLUMN_ID, COLUMN_title, COLUMN_Note,
                            COLUMN_nd

public long delete(int i){
        db = dbhelper.getWritableDatabase();
        return db.delete(TABLE_VIEW, COLUMN_ID + "="+i,null);

    }
```

Comment: IDs are supposed to be permanent. Why do you want the other IDs to decrease?

Comment: to remove gaps in IDs after deleting a row,when delete row with id:2 row with id:3 to end decrease and IDs change to 1,2,3,4,... .

Comment: And why do you not want gaps?

Comment: in a listview gaps make trouble.when id:2 is deleted in a listview id:3 is in 2 position.

Comment: Position and ID will be different once you do sorting or filtering. You must always access records by their ID.

Comment: TNX.i solve it by your idea.